# Matching emails from second column in one file against another file

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have two files, one with emails in it(useremail.txt), and another with email:phonenumber(emailnumber.txt).

useremail.txt contains:

```
John smith:blabla@hotmail.com

David smith:haha@gmail.com
```

emailnumber.txt contains:

```
blabla@hotmail.com:093748594
```

So the solution needs to grab the email from the second column of useremail and then search through the emailnumber file and find matches and output John smith:093748594, so just the name and phone number.

I'm on windows so I need a gawk or grep solution, I have tried for a long time trying to get it to work with awk/grep and can't find the right solution, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another in (GNU) awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    # RS=ORS="\r\n"       # since you are using GNU awk this replaces the sub()
    FS=OFS=":"            # input and output field separators
}
NR==FNR {                 # processing the first file
    sub(/\r$/,"",$NF)     # remove the \r after the email OR uncomment RS above
    a[$2]=$1              # hash name, index on email
    next                  # on to the next record
}
($1 in a) {               # if email in second file matches one in hash
    print a[$1],$2        # output. If ORS uncommented above, output ends in \r
                          # if not, you may want to add it to the print ... "\r"
}' useremail emailnumber
```

Output:

```
John smith:093748594
```

Since you tried the accepted answer in Linux and Windows and you use GNU awk, in the future you could set `RS="\r?\n"` which accepts both forms, `\r\n` and bare `\n`. However, I've recently ran into a problem with that form in a specific condition (for which I've not yet filed a bug report).

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
 awk -F":" '(FNR==NR){a[$2]=$1}(FNR!=NR){print a[$1]":"$2}' useremail.txt emailnumber.txt
```

If there are entries in `emailnumber.txt` with no matching entry in `useremail.txt`:

```
awk -F":" '(FNR==NR){a[$2]=$1}(FNR!=NR){if(a[$1]){print a[$1]":"$2}}' useremail.txt emailnumber.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, it's just printing out a bunch of emails with : in front of them, emails from the emailnumber file that arn't even in the useremail file. Is your command compatible with gawk? I have tried on cygwin and same thing.

Comment: Can you please provide a larger example data set? For me, it works with the given data.
Can you please check again? I mixed $2 with $1.

Comment: Yea I found that $2/$1 thing but after using your second version it makes sense, it appears it's not matching up for whatever reason. I tried on my linux VM and it works fine, guess I will just have to move the files across, thanks a lot man.

Comment: It's because you have Windows line-endings ie. `\r\n` and emails will be processed as `blabla@hotmail.com\r`. Use `sub(/\r$/,"",$NF)` when processing `useremail.txt` to remove the `\r`, or similar whatever suits your scheme.